# Removing a JavaScript property inside a specific Object within an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iteration

I have an object that looks like this when I do a `stringify()`:

```
{"key-1":{"inner_key_obj-1":{"A":"1", "AA":"11", "AAA":"111"}, "inner_key_obj-2":{"B":"2", "BB":"22", "BBB":"222"}, "inner_key_obj-3":{"C":"3", "CC":"33", "CCC":"333"}}, "key-2" : "not-an-object-property" }
```

I'd like to search for and remove they key `inner_key_obj-2` so that the object becomes:

```
{"key-1":{"inner_key_obj-1":{"A":"1", "AA":"11", "AAA":"111"},  "inner_key_obj-3":{"C":"3", "CC":"33", "CCC":"333"}}, "key-2" : "not-an-object-property" }
```

I know I can use `delete` to remove a key and its value from an object, but how do I loop thru this to get there?

I did some basic tests such as this:

```
  for (var key in object) 
        {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
            {                
                //Now, object[key] is the current value
                if (object[key] == null)
                { 
                    delete object[type];
                }
            }
        }
```

...but to no avail.  Can someone explain how to loop thru this?

Comment: Why would you need to iterate? Do you need to delete the sub-object with key `inner_key_obj-2` only in `key1`, or in any object at the higher level?

Comment: @jcaron  I am looking to delete a key at that specific position.  Basically, the first property in this object (key-1) is an array of objects.  I need to remove one object out of that array.

Comment: Is the object that holds the property always on the root object under the property `key-1`? Or you'd need to search for the object that holds `inner_key_obj-2` first?

Comment: it is always under the root, yes  @MinusFour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't

```
delete object["key-1"]["inner_key_obj-2"];
```

do what you want?

Comment: Why yes, yes it does!  I really overthought that one.  I am used to doing this stuff in php and in mind was thinking from a whole different viewpoint. Thanks!  Will mark correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just make a new object

```
var newObject = {};
for(key in object['key-1']){
    if(key != 'inner_key_obj-2'){
        newObject['key-1'][key] = object[key-1][key];
    }
}
```

Or

```
delete object["key-1"]["inner_key_obj-2"];
```